Cleveref does not use custom equation tags anymore
Referencing an equation with a custom tag with \cref no longer returns the tag. Instead it returns the equation number. I guess this is since the November 1 update. Is there a way to fix it?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
  a^2 + b ^2 = c^2 \tag{Pythagoras} 
\end{equation}
\cref{eq:1}
\end{document}



you could use \ref{eq:1} or \eqref{eq:1}.

@UlrikeFischer Thank you! I have a rather long document, so I was hoping to not manually change every cref instance.

You can use zref-clever instead of cleverref:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{zref-clever}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
  a^2 + b ^2 = c^2 \tag{Pythagoras} 
\end{equation}
\zcref{eq:1}
\end{document}


Or:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcLanguageSetup{english}{
  type = equation ,
  gender = N ,% useless for English but maybe useful when changing names of other languages
  Name-sg = Eq. ,
  name-sg = eq. ,
  Name-pl = Eqs. ,
  name-pl = eqs. ,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
  a^2 + b ^2 = c^2 \tag{Pythagoras} 
\end{equation}
\zcref{eq:1}
\end{document}

or (as the author told in a comment) even better:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{abbrev}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
  a^2 + b ^2 = c^2 \tag{Pythagoras} 
\end{equation}
\zcref{eq:1}
\end{document}

both resulting in:

Using zref-clever is often an option, because it is under active development.

Thank you very much! I'll have a look at this package.

+1 :-) But no need for the language setup in the second document, English already has abbreviations defined for equation, just use \zcsetup{abbrev}. And you probably wouldn't want to override the non-abbreviated names regardless, use the -ab names, if needed. (Off-topic, english is not declared with gender, hence the warning you get there from gender = N).

@EuklidAlexandria you could add \NewCommandCopy\cref\zref, then you perhaps continue to use \cref in the document (I don't know if they have the same syntax everywhere, but it will at least save some time).

@UlrikeFischer No, they don't quite share the same syntax, in particular \zcref takes an optional argument to modulate behavior, instead of alternate commands (e.g. \zcref[S]{label} instead of \Cref{label} etc.). So I wouldn't recommend doing that.

@gusbrs but you could emulate most of cleveref commands with zref commands?

@UlrikeFischer I'd say the functionality yes, mostly. But the translation is not always as simple as \let\cref\zcref. \zcref is not a drop in replacement of \cref. Of course, everyone is free not to follow the recommendation. But I really don't see why avoid some search and replace...

@gusbrs For testing the migration of existing large documents that use a lot of different cleveref commands, a zref-clever option cleveref similar to biblatex's option natbib would indeed be very useful.

@cabohah Sorry, but no chance. Not having to deal with legacy is a big advantage, which I'm not willing to let go. The cost of switching should be small, but it is not nil.

@gusbrs it would be imho very useful if there were some emulation code. A command \zrefactivatecleverefemulation would make if possible e.g. for pandoc to drop cleveref.

@UlrikeFischer We were writing at the same time, I guess, but I think I answered that already. ;-)

@gusbrs I'm not asking that you add that to your package, but if you could write down some definitions for an emulation it would nice. I could ask a question about that ...

@UlrikeFischer Sorry, but not even that. The translation of options specially would probably be not trivial. Besides, I have no intention of stimulating "mindless switch" of users for a package I warn to be experimental. My advice in that regard at the end of https://github.com/gusbrs/zref-clever/issues/9#issuecomment-1094134738 still stands.

@gusbrs Wouldn't this be one more reason why an cleveref emulation would be useful?

@cabohah The "emulation" I was willing to provide is called "User manual", and that's already available. ;-) Plenty of examples there for common tasks, some discussion as well.

@cabohah One clarification, for the record. I said it is "non trivial" to provide a general "emulation" between the packages, and I do think it is so (compare, for example, cleveref's \crefformat and friends with zref-clever's refbounds). Now, that said, it is usually quite easy to find the correspondence for particular tasks, in a given environment. Neither package is a subset or a superset of the other, but most common usage cases should be covered without much fuss. (Again, which is not to say "no fuss at all").

Using \tag in an equation is actually wrong: With hyperref the links will be faults. If you use the starred version everything works fine:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\cref{eq:a}, \cref{eq:b}
\begin{equation*}\tag*{$*$}\label{eq:a}
  a
\end{equation*}

\newpage 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:b}
  b
\end{equation}

\end{document}


